# I lost 15 reputation and I can't find any records of why

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, reputation

I note that since the [Recent Reputation History Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes), the reputation changes are updated immediately and with more details. But, today, at one point of time, my reputation on Ask Ubuntu just dropped from 6395 to 6380. I tried looking into the cause but I don't see anything different. No accepted answer unaccepted. No rash of downvotes. It doesn't look like any of my posts got deleted. Just to clarify, I was indeed looking at the reputation history with the checkbox for *Show removed posts* ticked. I can't think of any reasons that would have resulted in the reputation drop. And, askubuntu.com/reputation showed 6380 at that point of time.  So, triggering a rep recalc wouldn't have done any difference.

I am considering this a bug since it is not intended.

Does it help that I suffer from chronic OCD since I started using Ask Ubuntu and would always like to know exact accounts of my reputation changes?

(*Since then, I have answered a couple more answers and gained some upvotes and reputations. So, my current reputation will not reflect what I am reporting.*)

---

I'll recount my events so it is easier for debugging purposes. (All times in UTC.)

Friday 27 April
1500 After making a slew of tag wiki edits, I log out for the night. Rep count 6350
0000 Received another upvote before the UTC day ends. Rep count 6360

Saturday 28 April
0200 One of my answers is accepted and upvoted twice. Rep count 6395
0200 - 0630 Between this time, I lose 15 rep. I can't find the cause. Rep count 6380
*Funny thing is, once I figure that I lost 15 rep, the previous day rep count ends as 6345 thereby invalidating my claim that I lost the rep.*
0630 [I whine in the Tavern that "i just 15 rep but i see no records of it in my rep history.[sic]"](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/950319#950319)
0830 Received another upvote. Rep count 6390
1300 The [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126974/how-do-i-install-google-chrome-nightly-in-ubuntu-12-04/126981#126981) Nick refers to is **created**. Rep count 6390
1545 I created this meta question. Rep count 6505

Not to sound pedantic..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update: Found *another* -15 change around the same time, here's the actual cause.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116801/is-there-a-way-to-get-2x2-workspaces-in-gnome-3-x/117540#117540) was [merged](https://askubuntu.com/posts/116801/revisions), so your answer was unaccepted when that happened (first accepted answer wins).  However, your reputation wasn't synced up until another post you downvoted was deleted (necessitating a re-sync of all those involved) which happened at `2012-04-28 06:07:38.493 UTC`, but the vote for being accepted was actually deleted at `2012-04-24 19:50:29.130 UTC` (remember, late sync) so that's when it appears in the change log.

You can see the change [happened on the 24th](https://askubuntu.com/users/25798/jokerdino?tab=reputation), it was a late sync that you're seeing...but your reputation is correct.  **In the future, this rep change will happen within 5 minutes of the post being merged**, that should eliminate any confusion going forward.

Comment: I doubt that was the case because I remember having 6360 at 0000 UTC yesterday and not the 6345 that it is currently showing. Can you look into this one more time please?

Comment: AND, the loss I am reporting happened way before I answered that question. To be exact, around the time of 0600 UTC. I only answered that question you are linking at about 1300 UTC.

Comment: @jokerdino - see the update...your rep is correct, but I'll certainly take a look and see if we can make this instant.

Comment: Thanks. I can see that the answer has been unaccepted on April 24 in my rep history but I don't remember seeing it on that particular day itself. Now that the issue is cleared, thanks again!

Comment: @jokerdino - not a problem...I will be pushing code to improve this for this exact case going forward, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I don't think the first accepted answer wins... rather, it's the accepted answer on the master question (if any) that wins.