# 500 reputation drop - where did it go?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, reputation

When I visited StackOverflow today I noticed a sharp drop (exactly 500 rep): https://stackoverflow.com/users/81179/christophed?tab=summary ...

The strange thing is I can't pinpoint exactly where it went (although I've searched a little for usable culprits like deleted questions etc.).

The user reputation leagues still show the 'original' reputation: https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2012-06-03/81179#81179

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Did you click the `show removed posts` at the bottom of the reputation page? It is very likely a user was deleted and all the reputation you got from them is gone as well (will appear in red).

Comment: I browsed 22 pages of reputation and found exactly one `removed user` (-10). So that would not explain it completely...

Comment: I'd expect it on the first page, sorted by date descending. If you can't find it, I can't explain it. Does the reputation page tally with the [reputation audit page](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation)?

Comment: The rep audit page shows the 'new' reputation (with 500 rep *gone*). It looks like I've hit some sort of `great rep recalc` alike event. Very strange since I thought that rep was changed last year to be semi - continuous...

Comment: My guess is a bounty that somehow got revoked. Do you remember ever winning a 500 points bounty?

Comment: No, I certainly didn't (I would surely remember) ;-) I did once *offer* a 500 points bounty (on this question, at a time when code-golf was still allowed at the site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858384/code-golf-playing-tetris)

Comment: So guess only mod can see what's going on sorry. By the way when replying to comments, please use `@` to notify e.g. `@Shadow` otherwise people might not see you replied.

Comment: Really strange, may be a case for a dev to look into... for the record, your October '10 bounty shows up in your graph, and in the receiving user's graph, so I can't see how that could have caused the drop. Neither the question nor the answer was closed or deleted recently (as far as I can see)

Comment: There's churn on your Tetris code golf question.  You put a 500 bounty on it so that's a match.  It got undeleted 14 hours ago.

Comment: @UphillLuge: you are right. If you make this an answer, I'll upvote and give you the checkmark. I put a bounty on a question (500 points), it got deleted (at this point I probably got the bounty points refunded, don't really remember). When it got undeleted again, I `repayed` for the bounty. That's a logical explanation ;-)

Comment: Still interesting: did your reputation page not show anything about this? When things get deleted, you (should) see that in the overview. I kind of would expect the same to happen for undeletions, and/or for bounties. If not, this might be a bug after all.

Comment: @Arjan I believe it only shows the entry on that particular day when he put up a bounty. If you could take the pain and scroll to the October '10, you should see it there.

Comment: True, @jokerdino, but *changes* to the reputation are nowadays also shown on the date the changes happen. Like unupvote, undownvote and deletion. Hence, I feel a bounty should be shown like that too. I feel this specific 500 points should *also* be shown as added (returned) when the question got deleted, and as subtracted again when it was undeleted some time later?

Comment: @Arjan I am only inferring from what [Nick had said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130617/177471) to one of my bug questions. IMHO, it should be displayed live as well. Let's see what the team has to say about this..

Comment: @Arjan, jokerdino: I scrolled to October 2010, only the -500 from the awarded bounty was there. There's no sign of the deletion ("18 april 2012") or undeletion ("10 june 2012") in the reputation history (with the tick `show removed posts` on)...